# Fetching data json with factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, promise, angularjs-factory

I am trying to learn how to fetch data inside factory. Currently I am using fetch data with the controller

factory.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Product', ['$http', function($http){
        return{
            get: function(){
                return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vicariosinaga/learn/master/products.json').then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        };
    }])
```

detail-poduct.js

```
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('productDetailsCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams', 'Product', function($scope,$stateParams,Product){
            $scope.id=$stateParams.id;
            Product.get().then(function(data) {
                $scope.singleItem = data.filter(function(entry){
                    return entry.id === $scope.id;
                })[0];
            });
}]);
```

product-detail.html

```
<a href="{{singleItem.url}}">
<p>{{singleItem.id}}</p>    
<p>{{singleItem.name}}</p>
<img src="{{singleItem.image}}" alt="{{singleItem.name}}">  
</a>
```

but when I change the code to move the fecthing inside factory like this
 factory.js

```
return{
            get: function(){
                return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vicariosinaga/learn/master/products.json').then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            find: function(){
                return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vicariosinaga/learn/master/products.json').then(function(response){
                    var singleItem = data.filter(function(entry){
                        return entry.id === id;
                    })[0];
                });
            }
        };
```

detail-product.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('productDetailsCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams', 'Product', function($scope,$stateParams,Product){
        Product.find($stateParams.product,function(singleItem){
            $scope.singleItem = singleItem;
        });
}]);
```

it gives me an error that data is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return `singleItem` from the `find` method promise. And then place `.then` over promise to get data from it.

```
find: function(id){
    return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vicariosinaga/learn/master/products.json').then(function(response){
        var singleItem = response.data.filter(function(entry){
            return entry.id === id;
        })[0];
        return singleItem;
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
Product.find($stateParams.id).then(function(singleItem){
    $scope.singleItem = singleItem;
});
```

Comment: but it still give error ReferenceError: data is not defined sir.

Comment: yeah i guess it before, but after i change like you do, i now have error the `id` is not defined. i dont know why its give me error. i just move it to the factory. i try  to add `find: function(id)`. the error gone but it didnt give me any output

Comment: yeah sir your update code just like my guess too. but didnt give any output on page . just blank space. just my imagine, do i need to change the html too?

Comment: I guess you should pass `$stateParams.id` parameter to find method instead of `$stateParams.product`

Comment: @vandi no problem, Thanks :)